# vector spaces are a balanced category

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, linear-transformations, abelian-categories, change-of-basis

I'm trying to understand that in the category $\text{Vec}$ of vector spaces and linear maps any monic and epic morphism is an isomorphism. The trick is to complete
a vector to a basis, **but** I do not understand the machinery there. Any dteailed hint ?

Comment: Show that the monic morphisms are the injective linear maps, and that the epic morphisms are the surjective linear maps. You may do these by basis completion or otherwise (most likely by using something else that has been proven by basis completion).

Comment: @darijgrinberg This is what I did or was trying to do, but I'm missing details!

Comment: 1. Any monic morphism $f : V \to W$ is injective, because if $f\left(a\right) = f\left(b\right)$ then $f \circ u = f \circ v$ for two morphisms $v : k \to V,\ 1 \mapsto a$ and $w : k \to V,\ 1 \mapsto b$ (where $k$ is the base field).

Comment: 2. Any epic morphism $f : V \to W$ is surjective, because the canonical projection $u : W \to W / f\left(V\right)$ and the zero map $0 : W \to W / f\left(V\right)$ satisfy $u \circ f = 0 \circ f$ and thus must satisfy $u = 0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I now almost understand but not quite. Why then $u=0$ and also **why** $f$ is surjective? Please be patient with me, I'm a beginner to linear algebra. Some argument using equivalence classes in $W/f(V)$ would help.

Comment: $u \circ f = 0 \circ f$ implies $u = 0$ because $f$ is epic. This, in turn, yields $W / f\left(V\right) = 0$ because every $w \in W / f\left(V\right) = 0$ lies in the image of $u = 0$. And this entails $f\left(V\right) = W$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg How do we know that $f$ is epic? I understand only that elements in $W/f(V)$ are of the form $w+f(V)$. As I've said I'm a complete beginner to linear algebra.

Comment: Well, we are assuming that $f$ is epic. The other directions (injective $\Longrightarrow$ monic, and surjective $\Longrightarrow$ epic) are easier and hold in any concrete category.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I can see now. But yet, how do we use **the completion to a basis** machinery ?

Comment: We don't, the result doesn't need bases. In fact it is true for $R$-modules, $R$ an arbitrary ring

Comment: @darijgrinberg But this contradicts your first comment: "You may do these by basis completion or otherwise (most likely by using something else that has been proven by basis completion). "

Comment: Yep, I somehow failed to realize basis completion is unnecessary back when I wrote that comment. Sorry!

Comment: @darijgrinberg Could you posssibly clarify to me also the idea in your comment "And this enatils $f(V)=W$" using equivalence classes $w+f(V)$ ?

Comment: If $A$ is a subspace of a $k$-vector space $B$ such that $B/A = 0$, then $A = B$. Indeed, if $a \in B$, then $a + A \in B/A = 0$, thus $a + A = 0 = 0 + A$, so that $a \in A$. This shows that $B \subseteq A$, so that $A = B$.